# How to pretty print Spark DDL string?

Tags: apache-spark, format, schema, ddl, pretty-print

The schema string I get using `.toDDL` is succint, but very unreadable for complex schemas. How can it be formatted so that it looks easier on the eyes with all the indentations and line breaks?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no direct function to format DDL.

I use below code to format / parse DDL. It will add `printDDL` function to `df.schema` or object of `StructType`

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- author: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- category: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- editor: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- isbn: string (nullable = true)
 |-- title: string (nullable = true)
```

```
scala> df.schema.toDDL
res86: String = author STRUCT<firstname: STRING, lastname: STRING>,category ARRAY<STRING>,editor STRUCT<firstname: STRING, lastname: STRING>,isbn STRING,title STRING
```

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

implicit class DDL(val schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType) {
    def printDDL: Unit = {
        val tableName = "_source"
        spark.sql(s"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ${tableName}")
        spark.sql(s"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${tableName}(${schema.toDDL}) USING orc")
        println(spark.sql(s"SHOW CREATE TABLE ${tableName}")
        .as[String]
        .head
        .split("\n")
        .filterNot(l => l.contains("CREATE") || l.contains("USING")).mkString("\n ", "\n ", "")
        .dropRight(1))
    }
}
```

```
scala> df.schema.printDDL

   author STRUCT<firstname: STRING, lastname: STRING>,
   category ARRAY<STRING>,
   editor STRUCT<firstname: STRING, lastname: STRING>,
   isbn STRING,
   title STRING

scala>
```